# Book recommendation multiple integration

Tags: integration, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book that treats multiple Riemann integration directly in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in particular the demonstration of change of variables.

Thanks, sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lately, I've been using a lot the textbook *Elementary Classical Analysis*, by Jerrold E. Marsden and Michael J. Hoffman.